# Multiple jsTree instances

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a database from which I make multiple queries and I want to display the results in different jsTrees.
The code I use to create one tree looks like:

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li><a>Iteration 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Story A</a></li>
            <li><a>Story B</a></li>
            <li><a>Story C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Iteration 2</a>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) 
{
    $('#container').jstree();

}
);
</script>
```

My problem is that this works for a known number of trees,but there will be a problem when I need to create n (unknown,changes depending on the fields in the database) number of functions(because each function refers to a specific div id).
So,my question is, how can one create multiple jsTrees?

Comment: Create them client-side or server side? Either way you'll need to generate the HTML for the tree and make the .jstree call on the root of each, which is easy enough to do multiple types or dynamically. Which specific part of that are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I try to create them on the server side. I can create the HTML for the trees with different ids for each div (tree) with a for loop. The problem is I don't know how to create the jQuery(function($)) with the required different parameters.

Comment: Well some jQuery libraries work correctly on multiple inputs so you might be able to give them all the same class and then call a single jstree on a selector for that class. But if you can generate blocks of HTML dynamically on the server you can generate an extra line of script for each tree dynamically can't you? Which web framework are you using?

Comment: Calling a single jstree won't do the trick.I tried and I got only 1 tree(the first one I created). As for creating that extra line of script for each tree,well I'm afraid I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You should be able to do it the same way you create the extra HTML for each tree in your web framework I'd think. OK, if not you can get a single selector with all of the tree HTMLs and call [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on it: this takes a function that acts on a single input and so you can just call .jsTree on that.

Comment: Yep,you were right!(about creating it in the same way I created the HTML for the trees). Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('div[id^="tree"]').jstree();` to apply js to all your trees

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this same issue so I started [a discussion](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/568) on github.

It seems that it's because of the storage of node ids into unique DOM `id`s.